# How do I get to the top or bottom of a really long script quickly?

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing an extremely long bash script and scrolling up and down throughout the entire thing is extremely tedious and a major hassle.

Comment: There is probably no one (or set of two) commands that work in all editors.  Please specify which one you're asking about.

Comment: @AshM - Hi and welcome to U&L. Can you please edit this Q so that it specifies which editor you're asking about? There are multiple editors and they all have different keyboard shortcuts, so it's difficult to provide you a clear cut single answer that would cover all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Using vi(m)

```
Shift-g  - go to last line
1 Shift-g - go to 1st line
N Shift-g - go to Nth line
```

You can also jump to any line with colon(Shift-;) N

```
:1
```

Comment: When I try Shift -1g, it gives me ":.,$!" in the command line, and doesn't bring me to the top of the script. Shift g however does bring me down to the bottom. I just can't seem to get to the top, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Slight fix. It is N Shift-g.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [cheat sheet](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html).

Press G (capital) to move to the end.
Press H to move to the top
etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using vi.

You can quickly move through a linux script from vi by using the page up and down keys on your keyboard.

You can also move to the front or end of the script by using `1G` and `G` while in vi as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one more option... If you're using `vim` like most of the responses seem to indicate `Ctrl+u` will move up a page and `Ctrl+d` will move down a page.